# How do I save the ID from a SelectList to the field of another table?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-6, razor-pages

I have two tables, Users and Roles, each user is assigned a role. Using Razor Pages I can create a new user and select their role from a dropdown list populated from the Roles table. When I try to save the new user I am creating a new role in the Roles table and the new role id is saved in the user table.

Role Class:

```
public class Role
{
    [Display(Name="Role ID")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Role Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Role Description")]
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Sales Rep. Class:

```
public class SalesRep
{
    [Display(Name="Sales Rep. ID")]
    public int SalesRepId { get; set; }
    // unnecessary code removed ...
    [Display(Name="Role")]
    public Role role { get; set; }
}
```

Create.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SalesRep.role" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="SalesRep.role" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.RoleList">
    </select>
</div>
```

PageModel Class:

```
protected void PopulateRoles() // called from OnGet()
{
    RoleList = new SelectList(_context.Roles, nameof(Role.RoleId), nameof(Role.name));
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _context.SalesReps.Add(SalesRep);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

This is not what I need, I need to save the new user with a RoleID from the Roles table and not create new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `<select asp-for="SalesRep.role"`, the type of `Salesrep.role` does not correspond to the value(RoleId) type of dropdown list.

If you are using relationships, you need to add a foreign key (roleId by convention) for your `Role` navigation property in `SalesRep` model

```
public class SalesRep
{
    [Display(Name = "Sales Rep. ID")]
    public int SalesRepId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // unnecessary code removed ...

    public int roleId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    [ForeignKey("roleId")]
    public Role role { get; set; }
}
```

Page

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="SalesRep.role" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="SalesRep.roleId" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.RoleList"></select>
</div>
```

Remember to apply migrations and update database.
Refer to [EF Core Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)